# How to resolve IE Webdriver server initial start page error - Selenium IE Webdriver with JMeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to integrate my Selenium code to JMeter. 
Test Plan is as follows:

```
Thread Group
    \_ Internet Explorer Driver Config
    \_ WebDriver Sampler (with Selenium Java code)
    \_ View Results Tree Listener
```

When I run the Jmeter script, IE opens up and shows "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." and does not proceed beyond that. The Jmeter sampler result however shows as passed.

The code runs perfectly fine when run it directly from Eclipse.

I have configured IE as per this link - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

What else am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check selenium version in both dependencies.

Comment: @pburgr I am using selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to execute Java code in the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/), what you think is `java` is actually [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) which is not fully Java compatible.

Try selecting `groovy` as the language, it's more Java-compliant, moreover [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use it for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly for [performance reasons](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and if it doesn't resolve your issue check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries.

The minimal working Beanshell/Groovy code would be something like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("http://example.com");
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you suggested by selecting both java and groovy. But the result was the same. IE opens up and shows "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." and does not proceed beyond that. Though the sampler passes in Jmeter, I can see the following error in jmeter.log file - `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`